# Does the convergence of the absolute values in L1 imply convergence in probability for the sequence?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

Let $X_{n}$ be a random variable such that $\lvert X_{n} \rvert$ converges to $\lvert X \rvert$ in $\mathbb{L}^{1}$. Does this imply that $ X_{n} $ converges to $ X $ at least in probability?

Answer (score 4):

No: take for instance $X_n=1$ and $X=-1$.